# maintain rate of animation with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, html

I've noticed that HTML game developers are recommending the use of `requestAnimationFrame` as opposed to a timer for the animation loop. I understand that this can be optimized by the browser, but how con you insure that the speed of your animation is consistent on all devices? If a certain device has twice the frame rate then a game will appear to play at twice the speed and look odd.

Are developers designing their code to dynamically adjust to the current framerate? This seems much more complicated than simply setting a timer for 60FPS, especially if the framerate changes during play.

Comment: Many games multiply movements by the elapsed time. Something like `x += v*deltaT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Game calculations involve a lot of real work; like any real work, it'd be ridiculous to try to mandate to the computer "Enforce that this function runs inside of 300ms". In fact, 2040's computers might run that work 10x as fast. `requestAnimationFrame` means "run this as often as possible". You'll find that lots of mathematical, smooth-application code in a well-developed engine tends not to run much of anything in fixed steps, but instead multiplies every number by scalar, like time (or gravity, or even a "current game speed" constant that allows your character to enter Slow Motion; or Pause easily)